# How to get touch points from center of layout in android

Tags: android

I was working on the onTouchListener which gives me x and y value of touch point it is giving w.r.to left corner point i,e left corner point is being (0,0) but i want center of layout to be (0,0) how to get the touch point w.r.to the center of layout?

Comment: Just write a function that will map one pair of co-ordinates to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)get the center of screen using

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
height = size.y;
float centerY=height/2;
float centerX=height/2;
```

2)Subtract the co-ordinate got from touchlistener

Not an ideal solution but that works..
hope it helps